Cordova errors resource-file colors.xml missing after clean
I'm am getting this cryptic error when I do:
cordova clean android
cordova prepare android

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "code" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('ENOENT')
    at process.set [as exitCode] (node:internal/bootstrap/node:123:9)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:32:22

I have narrowed it down to having something to do with this line in my config.xml:
<resource-file src="res/values/colors.xml" target="app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml" />

When the failure occurs, I looked for the presence of colors.xml and it is missing:
root@aaa08cb7ed25:/opt/src/testcordovabug/testcordovabug# ls -la platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May 17 00:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 May 16 23:55 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  237 May 16 23:55 strings.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  602 May 16 23:55 themes.xml

If I remove that <resource-file line from config.xml, then do:
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@12.0.1
cordova clean android
cordova prepare android

then the prepare succeeds. (colors.xml is present)
I need to customize those color values, and that line is exactly as recommended in the official documentation: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/12.x/config_ref/images.html#adaptive-icon-with-colors
I'll avoid doing the cordova clean android for now.  But this doesn't seem like correct behavior.
Versions:
cordova: 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
cordova-android: 12.0.1
node: v20.5.1
